# Django Rest Framework adding import in settings.py causes 403 error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework application with custom render and parse classes, set in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": (
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer",
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": (
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser",
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseMultiPartParser",
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser",
    ),
}
```

And at this point everything works fine.
But if I add import statement in settings.py like this:

```
from djangorestframework_camel_case.render import CamelCaseJSONRenderer
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": (
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseJSONRenderer",
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.render.CamelCaseBrowsableAPIRenderer",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": (
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseFormParser",
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseMultiPartParser",
        "djangorestframework_camel_case.parser.CamelCaseJSONParser",
    ),
}
```

I start to get 403 error.
Why is that? How may I fix it?

Just in case it somehow matters my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.postgres",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "corsheaders",
    "django_filters",

    "rest_framework",

    "my_porject.my_app",
]
```

Comment: 403 is permissions error. Are you sure it's this? Also, should `djangorestframework_camel_case` be an installed app?

Comment: have you override these render or parser classes?

Comment: I was going to override it, but I came to the error before doing it.